# Восстановление пароля удаленно через ldap

Tags: php, ldap

Недавно пришлось на проекте сделать авторизацию через удаленный ldap сервер. Скажите, есть ли возможность в этом случае сделать функционал восстановления пароля. Посмотрел по документации, нашел только метод смены пароля, который требует старый пароль. А сброса пароля не увидел.

Comment: `Посмотрел по документации, нашел только метод смены пароля` - cсылку на документацию покажите.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.ldap.php

Comment: Я подумал про документацию по ldap. Но да ладно. Я бы не делал функцию восстановления пароля, т.к. это требует хранение пароля в открытом виде. Функция изменения пароля (без требования ввода старого) - самое то. Но у вас возможно другие требования к системе...

Comment: "Функция изменения пароля (без требования ввода старого) - самое то." - я об этом и спрашиваю, как это сделать?

Comment: например так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835927/reset-a-ldap-password-with-php